# Add property to javascript Array similar to length

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to add property to javascript `Array` like length which do not get iterated over in `For IN` loop, but have different value for each instance created

Following code:

```
a = new Array();
a.dimension = 2; //add a new property to array
```

Here if in case `for in` loop is used to iterate `a`, dimension will also be iterated which I don't want.

Is this possible to add such property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use **[defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)** -

```
Object.defineProperty(a, "dimension", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: 2
});
```

This will create a property called `dimension` for `a` which will not be enumerated in the for..in loop.

You can define a function for creating properties like this -

```
function defineArrayProperties(object, property, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: value
    });
}
```

and then you can call it like this -

```
var b = [];
defineArrayProperties(b, "dimension", 3);
```

You can also create this function in the `Array` prototype and let all array objects inherit it by default -

```
Array.prototype.defineProperty = function (property, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, property, {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: value
    });
};

var b = [];
b.defineProperty("dimension", 4);
alert(b.dimension);   // will alert 4
```

A **[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUHjY/2/)** is here demonstrating both of the above approaches. I have created two array objects and enumerated all of their properties using for...in. Notice that `dimension` doesn't show up in any of the for...in.

**EDIT**

Your browser must support ECMAScript 5 in order for `Object.defineProperty` to work properly.

Comment: fails in for in loop, I still get dimension iterated var arr = new Array();
 
 Object.defineProperty(arr, "dimension", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: 2
 }); for (a in arr){ console.log(a);} //prints dimension

Comment: my bad...had added _dim to prototype somewhere in my code which was causing this...fixed that and it worked fine ..thanks a lot